# .Net vs SQL Server for RegEx and data processing?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, regex

I have created an application to load text files and extract values from it with RegEx. It then inputs the values into a database. It all works perfectly but my boss, who is a SQL guy with no real knowledge of .Net, has asked whether it would be better to just dump all the data from the files into the database and do the regex processing in there. I advised that I'd prefer having the processing in the .Net application, as I do think it is better, but couldn't articulate any valid reasons for this apart from the fact that storing all this data in the database is unneccessary and could take up a lot of space.

Can anyone shed any light on which approach would be better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using a Regex is necessary, the major stumbling block would be that SQL Server doesn't have any built in RegEx support, so to do it in the SQL Server would mean writing a CLR .Net routine and installing that onto the SQL Server.

Comment: Aha, just back using SQL Server after years of MySQL (which does have RegEx support) so didn't realise this was missing. If that is the case, there is no benefit to me in running it through SQL Server.